# .NET Rounding Help

Tags: .net, double, rounding

I have 10 fractional numbers (double type) that add up to 1. My client wants to show one decimal place in our grid and I've tried using the decimal data type, Math.Round (Away and Even), but I just can't get the numbers to add up to 1 (.98). My math skills are lacking and I can't figure out how to do this correctly. Any help would be great!

```
0.429068150 0.222531293 
0.091098748 0.062586926
0.053546592 0.047983310
0.031988873 0.024339360
0.022948540 0.013908206
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers seem to add up to something very close to one as-is.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to round a bunch of numbers for display purposes but still be able to do math on them and get the results you would've seen if you had not rounded them.

So to illustrate the problem real quick: 1.5 + 2.5 = 4, whereas 1 + 2 = 3. Rounding changed the numbers and that changed the result.

What you could do is display them in the grid rounded however you want, but keep the high fidelity (unrounded) version of the numbers behind the scenes, and do your totaling on that.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. i thought they would still be able to add up with the rounding applied. thank you

Answer (score 1):

They add up to `0.999999998000000`.  You're probably looking for format strings.  You can set them in your column's properties. (Without knowing exactly what you're using, I can't help further with where to place the format string.)

```
double i = 0.42906815+0.222531293+0.091098748+0.062586926+0.053546592+0.04798331+0.031988873+0.02433936+0.02294854+0.013908206;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N1}", Math.Round(i,1)));
```

That prints 1.0.  Notice the `{0:N1}`.  That says print the number with one decimal place.